# Can I tell vscode "open on this virtual desktop"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on two different projects on two virtual desktops.

I can open a new file from the command line with `code filename` to open the file in a tab of my existing vscode window, or `code -n filename` to open the file in a new window.

How can I tell vscode "if my current virtual desktop has a vscode window use it, otherwise create a new window on this desktop."?

This is on a Mac in case that affects the answer.